# Operation on 2 fractions

Tags: java, oop

I am writing code for my assignments about Java OOP. I have to do operations on 2 fractions but most of the time the output is wrong and I dont know why. I think there are problems with the simplify since the result is correct without simplify
if two fractions 0/8 and 6/14 the subtraction should be -3/7 but the output is 0/1
Thanks for the help !
Here are the code :

```
 class Fraction {


          private int numer, denom;


          public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
            numer = numerator;
            denom = denominator;
          }


          private int euclidGcd(int a, int b) {

            int remainder;
            while (b > 0) {
              remainder = a % b;
              a = b;
              b = remainder;
            }   
            return a;
          }


          private Fraction simplify() {

            int gcd = euclidGcd(numer, denom);
            this.numer = this.numer / gcd;
            this.denom = this.denom / gcd;

            Fraction result = new Fraction(numer, denom);  


            return result;  
          }


          public Fraction add(Fraction another) {

            int b = this.denom * another.denom;
            int a = (b/this.denom) * this.numer + (b/another.denom) * another.numer;
            Fraction result = new Fraction(a, b);  
            result.simplify();

            return result;  
          }


          public Fraction minus(Fraction another) {
            int b = this.denom * another.denom;
            int a = (b/this.denom) * this.numer - (b/another.denom) * another.numer;

            Fraction result = new Fraction(a, b);  // stub
            result.simplify();

            return result;  
          }


          public Fraction times(Fraction another) {
            int a = this.numer * another.numer;
            int b = this.denom * another.denom;

            Fraction result = new Fraction(a, b);  // stub
            result.simplify();

            return result;  
          }

          public Fraction divide(Fraction another) {
            int a = this.numer * another.denom;
            int b = this.denom * another.numer;
            Fraction result = new Fraction(a, b);  // stub

            result.simplify();
            return result;  
          }


          public String toString() {
            return numer + "/" + denom;  
          }
```

Comment: The simplest way is to take the input and go line by line using it. You can use debugger for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the minus function to:

```
public Fraction minus(Fraction another) {
    return new Fraction(this.numer * another.denom - another.numer * this.denom, this.denom * other.denom).simplify();
}
```